# Newbie to Web Design, Spacing issues

Tags: css, layout, spacing

Hello my name is Cole and I’m working on a portfolio site for my typography class. It’s looking good however there is a glaring issue, as you see my site is experimental and all the buttons are just images with links attached. when I scale the window down the images will crunch up and currently don’t want this to be the case. at best I’d like the whole head just to shrink. is there a way I can achieve this? Side note im not very good with code.

My Website: https://colesmxth.com/index.php/allinmyheader/

[this is the issue im having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxvEt.png)

[this is the desired output i want for all browser page sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcDgv.png)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: Welcome  to SO Cole, we would be happy to help you if you provide code here.  Also plz be specific to your problem how you faced it and what you tried to solve it. We can help in your problem but you have to write code yourself instead of expecting from us.

Comment: I'm certainly willing to try, though unfortunately I don't know how to code at all. our design program kinda screwed us on that department. a friend told me people could help me here but as for any code, there is none. I've just been using beaver builder for wordpress.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.